# Given a balanced binary tree of integers and an integer B, count the number of pairs (a, b) where: a is ancestor of b. and sum of val <=B?

Tags: python, tree

I was working on the above problem, my solution is correct but getting TLE (Time Limit Exceed).

Link to the Problem: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/k-distance/

```
class Solution:
    # @param A : root node of tree
    # @param B : integer
    # @return an integer
    def solve(self, A, B):
        have={}
        count=0
        k=B
        def recur(node):
            nonlocal have
            nonlocal count
            nonlocal k
            if node!=None:
                for key in have:
                    if abs(key-node.val)<=k:
                        count+=have[key]
                have[node.val]=have.get(node.val,0)+1
                recur(node.left)
                recur(node.right)
                have[node.val]-=1
        recur(A)
        return count
```

Am i doing anything wrong??

Comment: What inputs have you tried? What where your outputs? Were they different from the expected outputs?

Comment: Hi Bro, you can give it a try in the blow link. All test cases are also available 

https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/k-distance/